# How can I locate a cell with specific keys and variables in a table

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, statistics, probability

[Image of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXrnF.png)

I created this table using excel and loaded onto a jupyter notebook. For the following question.

Blood pressure (BP) in childhood tends to increase with age, but differently for boys and girls. Suppose that for both boys and girls, mean systolic blood pressure is 95 mm Hg at 3 years of age and increases 1.5 mm Hg per year up to the age of 13. Furthermore, starting at age 13, the mean increases by 2 mm Hg per year for boys and 1 mm Hg per year for girls up to the age of 18. Finally, assume that blood pressure is normally distributed and that the standard deviation is 12 mm Hg for all age-sex groups.

I want to be able to pull out the mean from the table I created given the sex and age. This is so that I can answer the question

5.3 What is the probability that an 11-year-old boy will have an SBP greater than 130 mm Hg?

So far I have this.

```
data.loc('M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's fancy indexing makes this pretty easy.

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
for i in range(3,14):
    data.append( ('M',i,90.5+i*1.5) )
    data.append( ('F',i,90.5+i*1.5) )
for i in range(14,18):
    data.append( ('M',i,112+(i-14)*2) )
    data.append( ('f',i,112+(i-14)*2) )
data = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['Sex','Age','Mean'])
print(data)

# Probability for a male 11-year-old?

print( data[(data['Sex']=='M') & (data['Age']==11)]['Mean'] )

# Probability for all males older than 12?

print( data[(data['Sex']=='M') & (data['Age']>12)]['Mean'].mean() )
```